# Repeat function limitation postgresql

Tags: postgresql

My query is the following:

```
SELECT id, repeat('*', integer) as experience
FROM table1
```

this results in the following:

```
id | experience

1  | **
2  | ***
3  | *******
4  | *
5  | ********
```

As you can see, id 3 and 5 do have 7 and 8 stars. I want my query to create a maximum of 5 stars. Is there a way to limit the repeat function?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the smaller of the two values by applying the least() function:

```
SELECT id, repeat('*', least(5, some_colum)) as experience
FROM table1
```

(this assumes that `some_column` contains the value to be used)

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT id
      ,repeat('*', (case when col_name >=5 then 5 else col_name end)) as experience
FROM table1
```